# CORS allow to login as an admin but do not allow put request

Tags: java, spring, security, cors

This is my `SecurityConfig.java` file content.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AdminService userDetailsService;
@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

public WebSecurity(AdminService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL, LOGIN_URL, "/register", "/ideas/add").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/teams", "/ideas", "/projects", "/cities", "/categories", "/teams/filter/**", "/ideas/filter/**", "/ideas/free", "/projects/counter", "/ideas/done").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/projects/approve/**", "/projects/done/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
    return source;
}
```

I am working on Angular CLI application and already have login functionality. For example if I delete `corsConfigurationSource()` method PUT requests start working, but admin function stops working.

Login function works perfect but PUT request are rejected and angular application gives me this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://good-works-summer.herokuapp.com/projects/approve/6' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

SOLUTION:

```
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are being blocked by CORS policy because you never said to Spring it needs to allow **PUT** requests :)

For now you just allowed **GET, HEAD and POST**, as mentioned in the docs for `CorsConfiguration.applyPermitDefaultValues()`:

> The following defaults are applied if not already set:
>
> Allow all origins.
>
> **Allow "simple" methods GET, HEAD and POST.**
>
> Allow all headers.
>
> Set max age to 1800 seconds (30 minutes).

You can increment your configuration with a few more lines:

```
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    
    config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")); -- Define which methods are allowed to pre-flight
    config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("my-allowed-headers"));
    config.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("my-exposed-headers"));
    
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource configSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    configSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

    return configSource;
}
```

The `config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"))` should do the trick, you can also use the `*` option to allow all methods, or customize it on your needs.

Documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfiguration.html#applyPermitDefaultValues--) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfiguration.html#setAllowedMethods-java.util.List-)

Comment: Hi there, would you mind check if in the headers which values are in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`? And also if in fact it is available in the headers.

Comment: I found solution my self. I will update this post with my solution, it was very similar to yours.

Comment: @GabrielėAgnėNormali, please post a new answer to the question instead of just complement the description. Mark it as accepted as well :) this will help others to find the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
return source;
}
```